# Efficient algorithm to find all peaks in a 2d array

Tags: algorithm

Given a matrix M of integers, a peak is an element of the array that is no smaller than its 4 neighbours (up, down, left, right).  There is a nice linear time (O(n) for an n by n matrix) algorithm to find a peak, for example in [these lecture notes](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec02.pdf) or a slightly simpler O(n log n) time solution in [this code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-peak-element-2d-array/).

Say I want to find k peaks, if that many exist. Is there a way to do this in O(n + k) or  O(n log n + k) time?

Comment: is it the MaxPool algorithm with kernel 3, stride 1 and padding for edges?

Comment: Oh sorry stride 1 maxpool is O(n^2)

Comment: @Mehdi I really don't know. It sounds quite different but maybe it isn't?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. If the array contains only a single peak and you want to find two, you have to read the entire array just to find out there is only a single peak.

Comment: Does the discrete grid represent a sampling of a continuous field, of which you wish to find the maxima?

Comment: You must pick every item in the nxn array, either to see if it's a peek or to compare with other items. So the *best* case is O(n^2), no matter what refined technique you use.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. If `k > 1` then the worst case performance will be `O(n^2)`.

The problem is with the "if that many exist" part. When the input contains fewer than `k` peaks, our algorithm can terminate only when we are certain that there are fewer than `k` peaks to be found. I will prove (below) that we can only be certain there are fewer than `k` peaks if we have performed `O(n^2)` comparisons between neighbouring elements.

**Proof**:

To be certain that an element is **not** a peak we must compare it to **at least** one of its neighbours - if that neighbour happens to be bigger then the element is not a peak. If we have not yet compared an element to any of its neighbours then it could still be a peak, and every comparison we do rules out at most one element from being a peak. Knowing that there are fewer than `k` peaks in our input is equivalent to knowing that there are at least `n^2 - k + 1` non-peaks, which requires that we have performed at least `n^2 - k + 1` comparisons, which is `O(n^2)`. For `k > 1` there exist inputs with `< k` peaks, and so in the worst case we will have to perform these `O(n^2)` comparisons before we stop our search.

**Note**:

The reason this problem does not arise for the case `k = 1` is because every input is guaranteed to have at least one peak. We stop the search when we find our first peak, therefore we never have to check that there are no more peaks to find.

Comment: Downvoted becaused I don't think this is the correct interpretation of the question - the question at least to me is asking "if there are at least k peaks, can we find k of them in O(nlogn+k) time?" Will upvote if it turns out I am wrong.

Comment: @myrtclecat What if you know beforehand that `k` peaks exist?

Comment: In retrospect -1 was harsh but the vote is locked :-/

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an `NxN` matrix `A`. Initially `A[i][j] = i+j`. There is only one peak. It is easy to find it, but you are trying to find two peaks as fast as you can. The problem is, you are watched by a malicious demon that is allowed to change the value of a single element you have not visited yet. Obviously you cannot find the second peak quickly because the demon knows your moves.

Formally, suppose an algorithm can find up to two peaks in a matrix without visiting all elements. Run it on the `A[i][j] = i+j` matrix. It should return the single existing peak. Examine which elements were visited. Change a non-visited element to `3*N`, which makes it a new peak, and run the algorithm again. It must return the same answer as before, which is now incorrect.

So the answer is no.

If one only allows inputs with at least k peaks, the same kind of argument works, it only needs to be changed a little bit.

Suppose an algorithm can find two peaks when there are in fact two or more peaks in the input while visiting `M<N^2` elements. WLOG we can assume that when presented with an input that only has one peak, the algorithm visits all the elements (if not, we can always modify it to do so without losing its ability to process inputs with two peaks fast, e.g. by switching to brute force search after M visits). Present it with the `A[i][j] = i+j` matrix. The algorithm will visit all elements. Notice which element was visited last and change it to be a peak (if the last element *is* a peak, change the second last visited element to also be a peak). Run the algorithm again. Now the input has two peaks, but the algorithm still needs to visit all elements to find them.

Comment: Downvoted becaused I don't think this is the correct interpretation of the question - the question at least to me is asking "if there are at least k peaks, can we find k of them in O(nlogn+k) time?" Will upvote if it turns out I am wrong.

Comment: In retrospect -1 was harsh but the vote is locked :-/

Comment: @zw324 The same kind of argument works for your interpretation of the question, I will edit the answer and then you can re-vote.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I'm missing something, since a "yes" answer seems obvious to me.  Use the given algorithm to find a peak, but don't stop when found.  Instead, backtrack; keep looking until you've found `k` peaks, or you've exhausted your divide & conquer algorithm.

In some pathological cases -- such as several starting points leading to a known peak -- you can improve the performance by arranging the search order.  When you backtrack up the tree and then move across the breadth, do *not* move to an adjacent location.  Rather, move to the *farthest* un-searched node.  You can find this with an **O(1)** distance function, or simply grab one that's sufficiently far, given the level of the search tree (an excellent estimate of the sub-matrix size).

My mind's back-burner is working on a matrix that would contain `k` distinct peaks, but *not* solve reasonably well with this approach.  Connectivity of 2-D maze design gives a lot of good tools -- this is equivalent to finding a maze path from a given starting point.

Comment: I seem to have two no's and one yes so far.

Comment: The problematic part here is backtracking. In the case where the window maximum is on the boundary, you have no other place to go and will terminate early without finding all possible peaks. If not, you might backtrack such that you will visit more than a O(n) subarray.

Comment: "backtrack as you would had the search failed" The search cannot fail. There is always a peak. It is the basic assumption of the algorithm. Remove it, and it no longer works.

Comment: @n.m.  Bad wording; I was thinking ahead, to finding a peak already found through another path.  Fixing ...

Comment: If there aren't k peaks to be found, how does this approach know to stop without visiting (nearly) every element? In the worst case it seems to be O(n^2), but it still might be a pragmatic solution if the input usually contains at least k peaks.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: "terminate early"?  First, there's no peak on the boundary; the matrix is padded with `-inf` values.  Finding the global max isn't a problem; you're looking for other peaks, from other starting points.  I agree that, if the matrix doesn't contain `k` peaks, then this approach will go well past **O(n)** in exhausting all possibilities.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not the wording which is bad. "backtrack; keep looking" doesn't seem to be a well defined advice. Keep looking where exactly? If you just pretend that the first peak you found isn't really a peak (e.g. you set its value to -inf) then your new search is likely to return something that is not really a peak (e.g. one of the neighbours). Show an algorithm (and I will show you input where it breaks).